# How can I plot a user activities during 24 hour on a day based on server logs?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have server logs for each user which is in the following format:

| DateTime | Event |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-02-10 13:25:44 | login |
| 2021-02-10 13:26:08 | Run Script |

I have separate logs for each user, so all events are conducted by one user. The example above is not inclusive of all columns and this is formatted/cleaned up data. The events are not of interest, what I am trying to plot is the activity of the user X on a given day by the hour, i.e.

A chart (x-axis: dates, y-axis: 24 hour) showing user X had 2 activities between 1-2 PM.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [`seaborn`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/). It can be installed by the following command:

```sh
pip install seaborn
```

### Code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# Create the sample dataframe
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('DateTime,Event\n2021-02-10 13:25:44,login\n2021-02-10 13:26:08,Run Script\n'))

# Ensure that DateTime column is the proper datetime type
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

# Assign date and hour columns
df = df.assign(Date=df['DateTime'].dt.date, Hour=df['DateTime'].dt.hour)

# Make a pivot table and reindex
df = df.pivot_table('Event', 'Hour', 'Date', aggfunc='count').reindex(range(24)).fillna(0)

# Visualize the data as heatmap
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(16, 9))
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, cmap="Blues", ax=ax, cbar_kws={'label': 'The number of events'})
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Hour')
ax.set_yticks([i for i in range(25)], [i for i in range(25)])

# Save the figure
fig.savefig('out.png', bbox_inches='tight', facecolor='white')
```

### Output:

If there are more data points than what you provided, the output looks like this:

```py
# Another dataset with more data points
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': pd.date_range('2022-02-12', periods=10080, freq='T'), 'Event': ['some event' for _ in range(10080)]}).sample(1000, random_state=23)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot!